# How to implement Google Recaptcha v2 to the web application that has restricted access to Google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, angular, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Let me tell you the use case,

We are developing an application that does financial operations in the closed network i.e. it will not have access to the Google api. Given that, I need to know if there is any possibility of having our own google recaptcha implemented in our on premises.

Comment: Why not just have Google’s reCAPTCHA APIs white-listed if you require the use of reCAPTCHA?

Comment: @esqew It is not possible as the application should be restricted to any external communication due to security concern. It is the basic norms for banking applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without network connection to `Google Services` there is no way to get needed data for the captcha generation (It at least has to get images). There are other solutions for the simpler captcha implementations like [here](https://dev.to/movingmelody/build-a-captcha-code-generator-using-javascript-2ea6)